# How to reset password of user in Azure AD B2C via Graph API?

Tags: azure, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-b2c

How to reset the password of the user using Microsoft Graph API?
Is there a way to do it? If yes, I am not able to find a way to do it.

Please let me know , How this can be achieved?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The approach suggested by [Chris](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7378174/chris-padgett) is the recommended.
As I wrote in this post ([permissionissue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51536135/9395943)) you should also take care of proper permission configuration as you can change the password from your application only if you give to it the right privilege.

In the Reset Password flow, is not possible to impersonate the user, because you doesn't have user's credentials, so you should grant admin privileges to the application that makes the call for other users.This implies you must trust the application's code and use it carefully.

I used to grant the Helpdesk Administrator role to my app which is enough to change password to other users.
Through this powershell script:

```
Install-Module MSOnline
Install-Module AzureAD
Connect-MsolService
Connect-AzureAD

$applicationId = "{your app ID}"
$sp = Get-MsolServicePrincipal -AppPrincipalId $applicationId
Add-MsolRoleMember -RoleObjectId <your Role ID> -RoleMemberObjectId $sp.ObjectId -RoleMemberType servicePrincipal
```

You should run this code using a User with Administrator Privileges on your Active Directory.
You can get the propert roleID using this command:

```
Get-AzureADDirectoryRole
```

Now your app has enough privileges to call the PATCH method to change the password for other users.

Answer (score 1):

You can reset a user's password by PATCHing the user object:

```
PATCH https://graph.windows.net/myorganization/users/{user_id}?api-version=1.6

{
    "passwordProfile": {
        "password": "{password}",
        "forceChangePasswordNextLogin": false
    },
    "passwordPolicies": "DisablePasswordExpiration"
}
```

For more information, see [Reset a user's password](https://msdn.microsoft.com/Library/Azure/Ad/Graph/api/users-operations#ResetUserPassword).

Comment: Can we do this using client sdk (C#) of Microsoft Graph.
I think the example that you have shared above is Microsoft AD Graph API

Comment: As described by [Azure AD B2C: Use the Azure AD Graph API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-devquickstarts-graph-dotnet), it is recommended that you use the Azure AD Graph API for managing users, including resetting a user's password.

Comment: Now that the Azure AD Graph API is deprecated, it's recommended to use the Microsoft Graph API. But the method to [reset the password](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-update?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#example-3-update-the-passwordprofile-of-a-user-to-reset-their-password) is almost exactly the same.